# Time constant before and after effects Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to give a message display with Jquery

```
$('#ErrorPM').slideUp(500);
```

But I want the message to be stopped for two seconds .
And then be done for half a second effect.How can id do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setTimeout` (2000 is in milliseconds, meaning 2 seconds):

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
   $('#ErrorPM').slideUp(500); 
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use setTimeout like this.

```js
setTimeout( function () {
$('#ErrorPM').slideUp(5000);
}, 2000 )
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="ErrorPM">xyz</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use animate.

```js
 $( "#ErrorPM" ).animate({
    height: "toggle"
  }, 2000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="ErrorPM">error text</label>
```